# New to python and was wondering why when i put a grade into this program in comes out to be multiple letter grades?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
print ("Letter Grade Converter")
print ()
grade = float(input("Enter numerical grade:"))
if grade >=88:
    print ("Letter Grade: A")
if grade >=80:
    print ("Letter Grade: B")
if grade >=67:
    print ("Letter Grade: C")
if grade >=60:
    print ("Letter Grade: D")
else:
    print ("Letter Grade: F")
```

Comment: well, isn't that obvious? You check if the value is bigger or equal than the input, meaning if it is higher it will print out, and bring back the edit You just removed

Comment: @kioh, your question is less python-related, and mostly logic, since if you input a value more than `87`, it will test `True` for all the `if` checks, resulting in multiple outputs.

Answer (score 1):

Python will ask each question in turn, line by line, as you've written it in the code. A good way to see this in action is the debug mode in your editor. There are a couple of ways of dealing with this, if/elif would be the best way as you can then `return`/`break` the rest of the program. You could also set an upper limit for the question:

```
print ("Letter Grade Converter") 
print () 
grade = float(input("Enter numerical grade:")) 
if grade >=88: 
    print ("Letter Grade: A") 
if 80 >= grade <88:
    print ("Letter Grade: B") 
if 67 >= grade <80: 
    print ("Letter Grade: C") 
if 60 >= grade <67: 
    print ("Letter Grade: D") 
else: print ("Letter Grade: F")
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use if..elif..elif..elif..else so as soon as one if/elif statement is True it won't keep checking and executing blocks.
in your case, if..if..if..if, each if statement will be executed and so its block, and the last else goes on the last if.